# How are definition 1 and definition 2 equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

**Definition 1:**[Reference: *Metric spaces*, Micheal O Searcoid]

Suppose $V$ is a linear space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C $. Suppose $||·||$ is a real function
defined on $V$ such that, for each $x, y ∈ V$ and each scalar $α$, we have

• $||x|| ≥ 0$ with equality if, and only if, $x = 0$;

• $||αx|| = |α| ||x||$; and

• (triangle inequality) $||x + y|| ≤ ||x|| + ||y||$.

Then $||·||$ is called a norm on $V.$

**Definition 2:**[Reference: *Introduction to topology and modern analysis*, George F. Simmons]

Suppose $V$ is a linear space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C $. Suppose $||·||$ is a real function
defined on $V$ such that, for each $x, y ∈ V$, we have

• $||x|| ≥ 0$ with equality if, and only if, $x = 0$;

• $||-x|| =  ||x||$; and

• (triangle inequality) $||x + y|| ≤ ||x|| + ||y||$.

Then $||·||$ is called a norm on $V.$

> How does the definition 1 and definition 2 are equivalent?
>
> Suppose  $||·||$ satisfies the three conditions in the definition 1.
> It obviously satisfies the three conditions of definition 2. Only
> change in the definition is the second condition only.
>
> Suppose  $||·||$ satisfies the three conditions in the definition 2.
> Only change in the definition is the second condition only.
>
> each scalar $α $ scalar and $x\in V$ , $||\alpha x||=|\alpha|||x||$. Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb R$,
>
> Case 1:- $\alpha=0$, then condition (2) of definition (1) satisfies
> trivially.
>
> I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: As SmileyCraft said, the definitions are not equivalent. I believe the first is the standard one. I would guess that the motivation for the second is that those are the only properties of a norm that are used in showing that a norm induces a metric (absolute homogeneity is only needed in the case $\alpha=-1$). So it is sufficient to induce a metric.

Answer (score 2):

They are not. For example $\|x\|=0$ for $x=0$ and $\|x\|=1$ otherwise obeys definition 2, but not definition 1.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: What do you not understand? The fact that the definitions are not equivalent? The definition of my counterexample? My conclusion that it is a counterexample?